# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have a class that hits a secured URL (starts with https) with a xml and at their end it process the xml and send back the response. But while doing this i am getting some exception.
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I googled a lot and found so many answers but none of worked for me.
I added the certificate to my `cacerts` file under `../jre/lib/security` directory and also installed the certificate. but nothing is working for me.
I have also checked the certificate by running `InstallCert.java` file and it says No errors, certificate is already trusted.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same error. On my case it happened because there were mismatched with the JDK versions with my end and the 3rd party URL which I was hitting to get JSON data.

Comment: Thanks rabbi. will java version also cause for xml response?

Comment: I think it can happen for xml as well. Please check if Java version is mismatched?